# Python mailer dropping subjects from all except last in list

Tags: python, email

So I was working on an mail script to send mail to a list of users from text file. It works fine, iterating through the list, each user receives an email - except one detail, the subject is dropped from all emails except the last one sent by the script. What's happening here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage


targets = open('targets.txt', "rb")

def mailme():
    for line in targets:
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        m_source = '<sender@address.com>'
        m_target = '%s' % line
        smtp_server = 'mail.server.com'
        smtp_port = '25'
        msg['From'] = m_source
        msg['To'] = m_target
        msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
        smtp = SMTP()
        smtp.set_debuglevel(0)
        smtp.connect(smtp_server, smtp_port)

        message_text = ('Some Text for %s' % (m_target)
                        )

        message_html = ("""<body>
                        <h1>Some HTML for %s</h1>
                        </body>"""
                        ) % (m_target)

        txt = MIMEText(message_text, 'plain')
        web = MIMEText(message_html, 'html')


        msg.attach(txt)
        msg.attach(web)
        smtp.sendmail(m_source, m_target, msg.as_string())
        smtp.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mailme()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: just curious. What happens if you put `msg['Subject']` before `msg['From'] `? do you get the same error?

Comment: Weird, what SMTP are you running? What is in the "targets.txt" file? When you say "the subject is droped", does that mean the field ` Subject` or the content of the field or both?

Comment: When I say subject is dropped, I mean that the subject field in emails are blank (no subject). Only the final iteration (the last email address) gets the subject field properly populated. The targets.txt file contains email addresses.

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO - that's very peculiar, swapping the location of the msg['Subject'] actually worked. I'm not completely sure why though! Thanks!

Comment: great! I suggested because from all my classes and examples I see on https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html. Subject always come before To and From. Since it solved your problem I will post this as the answer but ask people to shed some light on this as of why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested OP to put `msg['Subject']` before `msg['From']` and it solves the problem. I suggested because the [python MIME email examples/tutorials](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) all have `msg['Subject']` comes before `msg['From']` and `msg['To']`.

I thought it is a template to follow. If anyone knows of why this approach solves the problem please shed some light on this.